# PersistentVolumeClaims Error with helm and Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to deploy Postgres in K8s with Helm. I build my k8s cluster with this link:
https://vitux.com/install-and-deploy-kubernetes-on-ubuntu/
But when i launch:

```
helm install my-release bitnami/postgresql
```

the resulting pod is "Pending" and when i use kubectl for describe the pod:

```
Warning  FailedScheduling  <unknown>  default-scheduler  running "VolumeBinding" filter plugin for pod "my-release-postgresql-0": pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims
```

How can i solve it? thanks in advance.

When i run `kubectl get persistentVolume`:

```
pv0003   5Gi        RWX            Recycle          Available           slow                    3m21s
```

When i run `kubectl get storageclass` i get:

```
standard (default)   local         Retain          Immediate           true                   17h
```

and when i run `kubectl get pvc` i get:

`claim1                         Pending                                      fast           28m claim2                         Pending                                      fast           7m57s claim3                         Pending                                      standard       6m58s data-my-release-postgresql-0   Pending                                      standard       30m myclaim                        Pending                                      slow           54m`

Comment: It is trying to dynamically provision volumes however your cluster will not have the capability to do so . You can make a storage class to existing volume and volumeclaim and use it with this chart.

Comment: How can i do it?

Comment: Kubectl describe pvc data-my-release-postgresql-0  and look for events , it will tell the volume it is looking for , you can make the volume or give it the volume which you already have. You can read through the options of helm also to provide existing claims.

Comment: Events:
  Type    Reason                Age                    From                         Message
  ----    ------                ----                   ----                         -------
  Normal  ExternalProvisioning  3m17s (x142 over 38m)  persistentvolume-controller  waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "local" or manually created by system administrator

Comment: Sorry but i'am new to kubernetes, how i can do what you say?